# How to clear off all resource checks in concourse

Tags: concourse

I had a resource that kept triggering every few minutes and it created a queue of hundreds of pending jobs.  I want to clear off all the old resource versions so that it stops trying to start new jobs.  How can I do that without deleting and recreating the pipeline or impacting any other active pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have something like:

```
> fly -t vm builds
id  pipeline/job       build  status    
25  queue-up/queue-up  25     started   
24  queue-up/queue-up  24     started   
23  queue-up/queue-up  23     started   
22  queue-up/queue-up  22     started   
21  queue-up/queue-up  21     started   
20  queue-up/queue-up  20     started   
19  queue-up/queue-up  19     started   
18  queue-up/queue-up  18     started   
17  queue-up/queue-up  17     succeeded
```

where maybe some of the builds are `pending` instead than `started`.

There is no way to clear off the old resource versions without deleting the pipeline. On the other hand, you can always abort all or some of the builds:

```
> for i in (seq 24 18); fly -t vm abort-build --build $i; end
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted
build successfully aborted

> fly -t vm builds
id  pipeline/job       build  status   
25  queue-up/queue-up  25     started  
24  queue-up/queue-up  24     aborted  
23  queue-up/queue-up  23     aborted  
22  queue-up/queue-up  22     aborted  
21  queue-up/queue-up  21     aborted  
20  queue-up/queue-up  20     aborted  
19  queue-up/queue-up  19     aborted  
18  queue-up/queue-up  18     aborted  
17  queue-up/queue-up  17     succeeded
```